# Injected class name for marshaling

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

The problem is around jaxb marshaling. Consider the following classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dog { //... }


@XmlRootElement(name = "dobermann")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dobermann extends Dog { //... }


@XmlRootElement(name = "pitbull")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pitbull extends Dog { //... }


@XmlRootElement(name = "animal")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Animal
{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    Dog dog;
    
    // setter
    // ...
}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String... args) {
      Animal animal = new Animal();
      animal.setDog(new Dobermann());
    
      // Marshaling to xml
   }
}
```

now, jaxb generates:

```
<animal>
    <dog> ... </dog>
    ...
</animal>
```

but I want:

```
<animal>
    <dobermann> ... </dobermann>
    ...
</animal>
```

or

```
<animal>
    <pitbull> ... </pitbull>
    ...
</animal>
```

Actually I want the xml element name depended on injected type.
How to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved, the Animal class has been changed as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "animal")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Animal
{
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "dobermann", type = Dobermann.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "pitbull", type = Pitbull.class)
    })
    Dog dog;
    
    // setter
    // ...
}
```

I think there is a better solution using `@XmlType`.